# Why is "requests" not working?

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, pip, python-requests

I have installed the python "requests" module using pip:

```
C:\Users\Isaiah>c:/python33/scripts/pip.exe install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...

C:\Users\Isaiah>python.exe
Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Sep 19 2006, 09:52:17) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

And get the error shown above when I try to import it. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

installed to python33

used Python 2.5

Comment: Wait so my "python.exe" refers to an old installation?

Comment: Try to set PYTHONPATH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor Look at the first line printed after you start python.exe: `Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Sep 19 2006, 09:52:17) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32`.  It tells you what version you are running.